# VNC Won't wake up my windows 7 laptop

Tags: windows-7, vpn, sleep, vnc, realvnc

I have a laptop running windows 7. It is running realVNC server. I have a mac that I want to use to connect to it. When the PC is awake, it works fine. However, when the PC is asleep, the viewer just hangs, trying to connect.

I see lots of information about VNC being able to wake up a Mac for some versions but not others, but nothing about PCs. Is three something I need to set up?

thx.

I should add that I am doing this with both machines on VPN. So its possible that the problem is that when the PC goes tosleep, the VPN closes?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable Wake On Lan on your Windows 7 laptop. This will ensure that when it receives a network connection request from your Mac that it will wake up and accept the connection.

It's worth noting that WoL doesn't work if your Windows 7 laptop is on wireless, it needs to be a wired connection.

Assuming you want to do that, then [this document](http://windows7-issues.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/wake-on-lan-wol-for-windows-7-made-easy.html) explains how to configure your computer and Windows. Since you are attempting to connect from within your local network, you don't need to forward the port on your router - that step is only required if you want to wake the computer up from a connection elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try running TightVNC on your windows pc. TightVNC server acts as a windows service and will should automatically wake your PC when it is asleep.  The other thing to look at is to make sure your NIC/Wireless card is not turning off to "save power".  This setting is in the device manager for the respective parts.

Comment: Additional details would make this a real answer.  Can you edit and add some detail such as how this helps the OP?